# Query NEAR RPC for delegators

Tags: nearprotocol, nearprotocol-validator

Is there a way to query the NEAR RPC for all current delegators of a specific validator? I checked the API docs, can't find something like this but seems like an essential function that has to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Delegators" is a staking pool contract concept, so you need to make a view-function call to the staking pool contract, specifically, call [`get_accounts()` function](https://github.com/near/core-contracts/blob/793e0594bab4e9cf730d37cd2a493a173b0e2ed3/staking-pool/src/lib.rs#L386-L393)

[NEAR RPC `query` method has `call_function` request type](https://docs.near.org/api/rpc/contracts#call-a-contract-function) which is used to make view-function calls.

Comment: Awesome thx, it worked. I'll add an answer with an example implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Vlad Frolov's answer here's an example implementation in JS.

```
fetch("https://rpc.<CHAIN_ID>.near.org", {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       },
       body: JSON.stringify({
            "jsonrpc": "2.0",
            "id": "dontcare",
            "method": "query",
            "params": {
                "request_type": "call_function",
                "finality": "final",
                "account_id": <ACCOUNT_ID>,
                "method_name": "get_accounts",
                "args_base64": btoa(JSON.stringify({
                    "from_index": 0,
                    "limit": 100
                }))
            }
        })
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        const result = JSON.parse(String.fromCharCode(...data.result.result))
        console.log(result)
    })
```